# Creating a class member pointer function variable that points to a non-static class member function

Tags: c++, class, function-pointers

The goal is to have the member variable `_AddValue` point to the `CreateFirstValue` function upon class initialization and after the first invocation of `AddValue`, all future calls to it will invoke `CreateAnotherValue`.

Previously, I just had a single `AddValue` function with a conditional check to determine which function to call. However, I feel like that implementation is flawed because that `if` check will occur every time and it seems like a function pointer would be beneficial here.

An example:

```
class Foo
{
 private:
  int _value;
  void (*_AddValue)(int value); // Pointer to function member variable

  void CreateFirstValue(int value)
  {
    _value = value;
    _AddValue = &CreateAnotherValue;
  }

  void CreateAnotherValue(int value)
  {
    // This function will create values differently.
    _value = ...;
  }

 public:
  // Constructor
  Foo()
   : _value(0), _AddValue(CreateFirstValue)
  {
  }

  AddValue(int value) // This function is called by the user.
  {
    _AddValue(value);
  }
};
```

The code above is not the actual code, just an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

right now I'm getting an error: `argument of type void (BTree::)(int) does not match void (*)(int)`

Comment: This code looks right to me, what is your issue?

Comment: The first error says "argument of type void (BTree::)(int) does not match void (*)(int)" I'm assuming I need to use the address-of operator, but when I add that, I get "ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function."

Comment: try _AddValue(0) in your cctor, and then within the body, _AddValue = CreateFirstValue.

Comment: @Hans: No can do, there is no decay from function name to pointer-to-member.  You need to use the address-of operator, and that requires a qualified name.  And works just fine inside the *ctor-initializer-list*.

Comment: No need to add "homework" to the title if the question is tagged as such.  Edited.

Comment: @fhaddad78 : Please do not edit your question with corrected code -- that just makes things more _confusing_ for future readers, who would wonder how you got that error with correct code. They can see the correct code in the _answers_.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> ```
> &CreateAnotherValue
> ```

This syntax is not valid.  To create a pointer-to-member, you have to name the class, even from inside other members.  Try

```
&Foo::CreateAnotherValue
```

In this case you are talking the address of a ***qualified*** non-static member function, which is allowed and prevents the error about address of *unqualified* member function.

Of course, you then need an appropriately typed variable to store the pointer-to-member in, see Bo's answer for the correct declaration.  When it comes time to call it, you will need to use the pointer-to-member-dereference operator (either `.*` or `->*`), so say

```
(this->*_AddValue)(whatever);
```

The same rule applies to data, if you say `&Foo::_value`, you get a pointer-to-member of type `int Foo::*`.  But in the data case, the unqualified name is also accepted, but with very different behavior.  `&_value` gives a normal pointer, type `int*`, which is the address of the specific `_value` member variable inside the `this` instance.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanation. I knew I had the general gist of all this right, just implementation was weird for me. Especially because our text book doesn't go into much depth with regards to function pointers. With your explanation and Bo's example, it's not compiling. Thank you!

Comment: Comment above should say ...it's now compiling... (=

Answer (score 7):

> void (*_AddValue)(int value); // Pointer to function member variable

This is not really a pointer-to-member, but a pointer to a free function.

You need to make this

```
void (Foo::*_AddValue)(int value); // Pointer to function member variable
```

Comment: @BoPersson With that change, I'm getting "btree.cpp: In constructor BTree::BTree():"
"btree.cpp:9:21: error: argument of type void (BTree::)(int) does not match void (BTree::*)(int)"

Comment: @fhaddad - You might need to use `&Foo::CreateAnotherValue` to take the address of the member function. That would match the `Foo::*` of the pointer.

Comment: with your help and Ben's it's not compiling. I knew it was syntax issues. I'm still quite confused on how one understands how all this stuff works. Lots of time when I am reading the compiler errors, I don't understand what they are saying.

Comment: Comment above should say ...it's now compiling... (=