# Clarification with accessing non-static class member function via pointer

Tags: c++, non-static

I am having difficulty accessing a non-static member function from a function pointer and can't quite figure out my syntax issue. When attempting to compile as seen below I receive "error: fnc_ptr not declared in this scope." and when if the code is modified to not access the function it should point to it compiles and will print out 1 for bar.fn_ptr .To compile I used:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall example.cpp foo.cpp
```

The split file structure/namespace is just meant to emulate the same conditions as my original issue.

example.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  pizza::foo bar;
  bar.fn_ptr = &pizza::foo::fnc_one;
  std::cout << (bar.*fn_ptr)(1) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

foo.cpp

```
#include <cmath>
#include "foo.h"

namespace pizza{

   double foo::fnc_one(double x){
        return pow(x,3) - x + 2;
   }
}
```

foo.h

```
namespace pizza{

   class foo{
       public:
        double (foo::*fn_ptr)(double);
        double fnc_one(double);

        foo(){
           fn_ptr = 0;
        }
   };
}
```

A very similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057206/creating-a-class-member-pointer-function-variable-that-points-to-a-non-static-cl), with additional reference [here](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html#defi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `bar.` when referring to `fn_ptr` which is an attribute of that object. Change it to:

```
  std::cout << (bar.*(bar.fn_ptr))(1) << std::endl;
```

And it works.

I also recommend reading this FAQ on the subject: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct syntax is:

```
//std::cout << (bar.*fn_ptr)(1) << std::endl;
std::cout << (bar.*(bar.fn_ptr))(1) << std::endl;
```